# Why I'm not getting value for each line?

Tags: bash

Why im not getting the number from each line in this code ?
Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash

seq=$(which seq)
a=2290
b=2300
gen=$($seq $a $b)

echo "GENERATING..."

for nr in "$gen"
do
        echo "hello $nr"
done

echo "DONE."
```

I'm getting this:

```
DOWNLOADING...
hello 2290
2291
2292
2293
2294
2295
2296
2297
2298
2299
2300
DONE.
```

Comment: What output do you get?  Have you tried echoing intermediate values?

Comment: not sure (yet) try with awk? `seq 2290 2300 | awk '{print "hello"FS$0}'`

Comment: @matchew your one-liner works +1

Answer (score 3):

Change `for nr in "$gen"` to `for nr in $gen`

Remove the quotes...its treating the entire sequence as a single item.

Output **Before**:

```
GENERATING...
hello 2290
2291
2292
2293
2294
2295
2296
2297
2298
2299
2300
DONE.
```

Output **After**:

```
GENERATING...
hello 2290
hello 2291
hello 2292
hello 2293
hello 2294
hello 2295
hello 2296
hello 2297
hello 2298
hello 2299
hello 2300
DONE.
```

Comment: Not n00bish at all.  I see people with 2-3k points forget the simplest syntax.  Don't beat yourself up.